# VueJS dynamic inputs avoid duplicates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a project where I allow users to add filters to alerts, what is the best way to avoid dupliated filters and to let users add one filter of each type?

```
<div class="filters_container" v-for="filter in alert.filters">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="filter.type">
            <option disabled selected value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="price">Price</option>
            <option value="sales">Sales</option>
            <option value="margin" v-if="alert.tool == 'classic'">Margin</option>
            <option value="trend">Trending items</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" v-if="filter.type == 'sales'">
        <label>Time frame</label>
        <select class="form-control" v-model="filter.timeFrame">
            <option disabled selected value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="daily">Daily</option>
            <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
            <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
            <option value="total">Total</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" v-if="filter.type != 'trend'">
        <label>Values</label>
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="filter.min" placeholder="Min">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="filter.max" placeholder="Max">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click.prevent="addFilter">Add Filter</button>
```

This is my add filter function at the moment

```
addFilter: function () {
    this.alert.filters.push(
        {
            temp_id: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)) * (Date.now()),
            type: 'trend',
            timeFrame: 'daily',
            min: null,
            max: null
        }
     )
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```js
this.alert.filters = this.alert.filters.filter((value, index, self) => 
{
  return index === self.findIndex(item =>
  {
    return item.type === value.type; // && item.timeFrame === value.timeFrame && item.min === value.min && item.max === value.max;
  });
});
```

Comment: How should I implemet it, add a watch to filters to call the function on change?
What happed if a user decieds to change type on an exsiting object?
I'll try and report back

Comment: It depends on what you want to do if there is a duplicate. If you are trying to add new filter which already exists - you should not add it. If you are updating an existing filter but there is already another filter of the same type - you should first remove the duplicate before continuing with the update.